# Jquery - if url has _edit in the link then dont show a div else show

Tags: jquery

Just wondering if there is a way that you can read and search for specific refferences within a URL, put it in a url and then do an if statement.

I want the code to be able to search for this refference "/_edit" and if its in the url then hide a div if it isnt then show it.

Answer (score 3):

On load of the current page:

```
$(function() {
    if (location.href.match(/\_edit/)) {
        $('div#editor').show();
     }
     else {
        $('div#editor').hide();
     }
});
```

Via a click handler:

Just use the string match method on the href to choose whether to show or hide the div.

```
$('a').click(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     if (href.match(/\/_edit/)) {
        $('div#editor').show();
     }
     else {
        $('div#editor').hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: sorry i meant on page load, when it loads up.

Comment: @Jake - no problem just match on `location.href` instead of the href of a clicked anchor inside the document ready handler.